# How do you make an <a> element circular?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` element that contains an `<img>`. The image is circular, and I want the link to be circular as well. I've tried:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/path/to/file.txt" style="display: block; border-radius: 50%;">
    <img src="image.png">
</a>
```

...but the link is still square, and it can be clickable outside of the circle it's supposed to be clickable in.

Is there any way to properly use `border-radius` with an `<a>` element?

Comment: @TJ It did what I wanted it to. It made the link fit exactly around the circular image. It didn't exactly made the `<a>` tag circular in terms of the code, but it did make the link circular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add border-radius to both the image and the a tag.

```css
a, img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/180/200/200.jpg?hmac=YtJJ-CeQThqv_K6NzUnKS6Q8-tjxUVkSKeDsStrjEyM">
</a>
```

Comment: This `<a>` tag is `200x18`, it's not circular. This is what OP already has.

Comment: @TJ No, it is circular. This answer worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @TJ That's just a display error in the Inspector. Tested in Mac Chrome and Firefox and it works in both. Just hover around the edges with your mouse, and you will see that.

Comment: You''ll get the same result without the `a` selector in CSS as well.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a, img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500">
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering, but [this answer was already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438765/13158153). But I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

It works in my device.

```css
a {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle();
  border-radius: 999px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/path/to/file.txt" style="display: block; border-radius: 50%;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this, it should work:

```
a, img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<a href="#"> <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/180/200/200.jpg?hmac=YtJJ-CeQThqv_K6NzUnKS6Q8-tjxUVkSKeDsStrjEyM"> </a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I just saw the question and answered. My bad. But hope it helps too. Inconvenience Regretted